# No data in resultSet - Jsp Database

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, jdbc

I have this basic code to get connection with oracle database and retrieve one column from table called temp_employee. However, when i compile  it does not display data on web page. It shows no error messages. Just a blank page. Could you help with making this code work properly?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import=" javax.sql.DataSource" %>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Database</title>
</head>
<body>
        <%
            Connection connection = null;
            try {
                // Load the JDBC driver
                String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
                Class.forName(driverName);

                connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:dev", "root", "root");

                Statement statement = connection.createStatement(); 

                ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT aadName from temp_employee");    
                while (resultSet.next()) { 

                    String code = resultSet.getString("aadName");

                }; 

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                 out.println("Driver caused Exception : " + e.getMessage() + "");

                // Could not find the database driver
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // Could not connect to the database
                 out.println("Database caused Exception : " + e.getMessage() + "");
            }

        %>          


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: do **not** put code like that into a JSP page. Create a Servlet or JSP Tag to handle the data retrieval. SQL code or calls to `DriverManager.getConnection()` should never occur in a JSP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your html body do some changes,
After Connection declaration, declare `String code = null;`
and change the existing code to `code = resultSet.getString("aadName");`
Then add below line in html body,
`<h2><%= code %></h2>`

Actually a scripting expression is used to insert the value of code into the output stream.